# High Train Set Accuracy, Low Test Set Accuracy, Tensorflow, Regularization, Dropout Tried

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to build a model using Tensorflow NN.

Input Matrix Size: [6699, m] -> 'm' examples; 
Output Matrix Size: [11, m] -> 11 output layer nodes with softmax implementation

I am consistently getting very high Train accuracy (>95%) and quite low Test accuracy (~20-30%). Some of the things I tried:

1. Increased training set size from around m = 1200 to m = 13000
2. Added Regularization (lambda = 0.5 & 0.7)
3. Added Dropouts (keep_prob = 0.5)
4. Gradient Descent and then Adam optimizer (which is useful only for speeding up the convergence)
5. Tried various values of learning rates
6. Tried changing number of layers and neurons in each layers. Again from shallow 1 hidden layer up till 6 hidden layers.
7. Currently using 1200 num_epochs, but the cost pretty much stabilizes after 500-600 epochs.
8. Tried some options on mini_batch size as well.

I have tried all these over last week or so. Still, I am unable to decipher what is causing so much divergence in training set and test set accuracies and I am getting this divergence for pretty much every scenario I described above. It's a clear case of overfitting and I am pretty much exhausted with the options.

Please suggest what more can I do.

Comment: I assume that you have shuffled your train and test sets, but if not it could be that the test set has a different distribution.

Comment: @mjul Yes I did. In fact, these get automatically reshuffled every time I try out a new simulation. Distribution is not an issue, everything comes from same distribution and gets distributed in training and test sets after reshuffling.